# Directly input accents in TexStudio?

Tags: texstudio, input-encodings

Is it possible to input directly accents in TeXstudio, instead of the hard-to-read form `\'a` for `á`? What do I have to do to get this working?

In TexWorks, I can input the accented character directly in the editor and it will render correctly in the compiled `pdf`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can insert accents directly by keyboard in TeXstudio.

Note that, since TeXstudio is an editor which support a lot of font encoding you can type normally. No problem will appear until you compile your `tex` file.

During the compilation process those accented characters should be interpreted by the compiler. This could be done *in general* loading some specific packages.

If your `tex` file is UTF, load the package

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

If your `tex` file is ISO load

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
```

You can discover if it is UTF or ISO in the TeXstudio status bar.

Also, load

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

and probably you will have no problems.

```
\'a \'e \'i \'o \'u 

á é í ó ú
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1, but why should I load `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I fail to see the difference between `fontenc` and no `fontenc`

Comment: @becko, if I'm not wrong, when you use `fontenc` and insert e.g. `ó` the output will contain a single glyph from the font. Without `fontenc` TeX and the `inputenc` will read `ó` and create a group of two glyphs in the output.

Comment: Let me add that, if a font has `OT1` encoding, it has no accented characters by itself, only ascii characters, and accented characters, as @Sigur said, are made up of two glyphs. This can cause problems with hyphenation.of languages with accented characters. The reason for this dates back to the times when computers had a very small amount of memory, which was very expensive. Another reason was the difference in encoding according to the oerating system, which made ascii the only universal input encoding. Nowadays, all systems understand `utf8`, so this is no more  necessary.

Comment: What about in TexStudio for Windows? I set Windows to be able to do crtl+' and then e (using the addition of US international keyboard), but it does not work in TexStudio editor. Thank you for your help!